# Listview row color different for each row

Tags: android, android-listview

Hello I am using a Listview with custom row layout . I have used LinearLayout in CardView inside the row layout of Listview. I have some gradients shapes in drawable so I want to give them to background of LinearLayout.. How can i give it to linearlayout problematically, so every row of Listview will be filled with different gradients. 
Every Row should have a different gradient background.
this is my row layout for ListView

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/card_iq_sidebar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/circle_purple"
                android:orientation="vertical"></LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code in where you control your custom row, so it changes background drawable according to adapter position. mainlayout is your linearlayout but my code uses just 2 gradient.

If you want different colors for every cell, define an resource array and use `getAdapterPosition()` for resource array index. (notice you can get out of bound error easily)

Info for resource array [android using xml array resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16616458/android-using-xml-array-resources)

```
        if(!(getAdapterPosition() % 2 == 0)){
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_dashboard_row_reverse);

        }
        else{
            mainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_dashboard_row);

        }
```

I hope you got the idea.