# Colors and Colors name

Tags: android, xml

I have a string array in strings.xml which is an array of color name. And, I listed colors in colors.xml with the same name as the array item. Now, I am trying to set the background of view using the color name (string) from strings.xml. How can i do that?

```
<color name="aliceBlue">#F0F8FF</color>
    <color name="antiqueWhite">#faebd7</color>
    <color name="antiqueWhite1">#ffefdb</color>
    <color name="antiqueWhite2">#eedfcc</color>
    <color name="antiqueWhite3">#cdc0b0</color>
    <color name="antiqueWhite4">#8b8378</color>
    <color name="aquaMarine1">#7fffd4</color>
    <color name="aquaMarine2">#76eec6</color>
    <color name="aquaMarine4">#458b74</color>
    <color name="azure1">#f0ffff</color>
    <color name="azure2">#e0eeee</color>
    <color name="azure3">#c1cdcd</color>
    <color name="azure4">#838b8b</color>
```

color.xml

```
<string-array name="colorNameArray">
    <item>AliceBlue</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite1</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite2</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite3</item>
    <item>AntiqueWhite4</item>
    <item>aquamarine1</item><item>
    aquamarine2</item>
    <item>aquamarine4</item>
    <item>azure1</item>
    <item>azure2</item>
    <item>azure3</item>
    <item>azure4</item>
```

strings.xml

Please guys, your help is appreciated.

Comment: I think you have to use a switch.

Comment: why you use colorNameArray ?? can you explain ?

Comment: spinner? Choose a color out of a list?

Comment: for your antique whites, i would suggest just switching it and if its one of the colors that work for Color.parseColor, use that as the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change

```
 <item>AliceBlue</item>
```

to

```
 <item>@color/AliceBlue</item>
```

change all of them, you need `@color/` before tag

for more info see:

[How can I save colors in array.xml and get its back to Color[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114587/how-can-i-save-colors-in-array-xml-and-get-its-back-to-color-array)

then you can get your colors as:

```
  int[] colorArray = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colorNameArray);
```

then you can set your color.

if you have more that one item and you need change all of them you can use following code:

1- create one Array of `View`

```
  ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();
```

2- add All view that you want set background to your list

```
  views.add(iv);
  views.add(tv);
```

3- in for statement change all background, like:

```
  for (int i = 0 ; i < views.size() ; i++ )
  {
      // set background with views.get(i) and colorArray[i]

  }
```

Comment: but the problem this is that you need to access the id of the color itself in R.java

Comment: ya @committedandroider i got i, i will edit my post but array of OP has a problem too

Comment: clever solution but wont work for his antique whites. Supported formats are:  #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB 'red', 'blue', 'green', 'black', 'white', 'gray', 'cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow', 'lightgray', 'darkgray', 'grey', 'lightgrey', 'darkgrey', 'aqua', 'fuschia', 'lime', 'maroon', 'navy', 'olive', 'purple', 'silver', 'teal'                      Will throw illegal argument exception if color is not one of those listed colors

Comment: thanks @committedandroider, i edited my code for that problem ,now i think this must be worked

Answer (score 0):

get a java object reference to the view. 
And call this method on that reference
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.color_name));