# Android Color Resource

Tags: android, colors, resources

```
<resources>

<color name="red">#e51c23</color>
<color name="pink">#e91e63</color>
<color name="purple">#9c27b0</color>
<color name="deep_purple">#673ab7</color>

<string-array name="colors_hex_code">
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/pink</item>
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/deep_purple</item>
</string-array>

</resources>
```

Hello, I declared colors.xml like about code and when I access this value form java like

```
String[] s = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.colors_hex_code);

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Color: " + s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

, why s[index] always return null? I would like to get hex color codes from "colors_hex_code" string array. Is it possible to access like this? Please help. Thank u.

Comment: Because it is not valid.. you can't define colors in string-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change string-array to integer-array:

```
<resources>

<color name="red">#e51c23</color>
<color name="pink">#e91e63</color>
<color name="purple">#9c27b0</color>
<color name="deep_purple">#673ab7</color>

<integer-array name="colors_hex_code">
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/pink</item>
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/deep_purple</item>
</integer-array>

</resources>
```

And java code:

```
int[] s = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors_hex_code);

Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Color: " + String.format("#%06X", (0xFFFFFF & s[0])), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably should not declare a "string-array" if you store colors and not string inside it.

Try to take a look at this post :

[How can I save colors in array.xml and get its back to Color[] array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114587/how-can-i-save-colors-in-array-xml-and-get-its-back-to-color-array)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `StringArray`

> ```
> <item> A string, which can include styling tags. The value can be a reference to another string resource
> ```

So if you want to have a `string-array` you have to declare the colours in `strings.xml`, or you

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<string-array name="colors_hex_code">
    <item>@color/red</item>
    <item>@color/pink</item>
    <item>@color/purple</item>
    <item>@color/deep_purple</item>
</string-array>
```

with

```
<string-array name="colors_hex_code">
<item>#FFEA4E3C</item>
<item>#FFF67A81</item>
<item>#FF665EC7</item>
<item>#FF3B3673</item>
</string-array>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array instead of string-array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="red">#e51c23</color>
    <color name="pink">#e91e63</color>
    <color name="purple">#9c27b0</color>
    <color name="deep_purple">#673ab7</color>

    <array name="colors_hex_code">
        <item>@color/red</item>
        <item>@color/pink</item>
        <item>@color/purple</item>
        <item>@color/deep_purple</item>       
    </array>
</resources>
```

and get color using

```
int[] s = context.getResources().getIntArray(R.array.colors_hex_code);

// It will show you a color code value
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "First Color: " + s[0], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a **colour.xml** file

Add some colours :

```
<color name="white">#ffffff</color>
<color name="black">#000000</color>
```

Then in  the activity :

```
textView.setTextColor(R.color.white);
```