# color-array from color.xml returns null for all items.

Tags: android, null, nullable

I have made an color-array containing 12 different colors in color.xml.
But in my attempt to extract the colors and use them in the code I get null for all values in the array. I also tried to use the TypedArray solution with no difference. So what is wrong?

```
    public void testColor(){

    Resources resources = App.getAppContext().getResources();
    String colors[] = resources.getStringArray(R.array.backgroundcolors);

    //prints null
    Log.d("TAG", " " + colors[3]);

    //prints 12x null 
    for(String x : colors){
        Log.d("TAG", " " + x);

    }
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    testColor();
}
```

**color.xml**

```
<array name="backgroundcolors">
    <item>#000000</item>
    <item>#373737</item>
    <item>#ffffff</item>
    <item>#e6e6e6</item>
    <item>#EAE1D8</item>
    <item>#fd79a1</item>
    <item>#ff0f68</item>
    <item>#E849A1</item>
    <item>#F7E84E</item>
    <item>#FFB732</item>
    <item>#48B1E3</item>
    <item>#5dd95d</item>
</array>
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114587/how-can-i-save-colors-in-array-xml-and-get-its-back-to-color-array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change:

```
 <array name="backgroundcolors">
```

to

```
<string-array name="backgroundcolors">
```

Comment: Oh that was it! the little missing "string" it worked!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to use `getStringArray`,  you should be useing

```
<string-array
```

as root tag instead of `<array` and content should be placed in `strings.xml`. `Colors` are `int`. You can use [getIntArray](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIntArray(int)) to retrive an `array` of `int` from the `res`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
 Color.parseColor(colors[i]))


Color.parseColor("#636161")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You should get the array as int array like this

```
int colors[] = resources.getIntArray(R.array.backgroundcolors);
```

**Solution 2**

If you want to read it as a `String` array then

change

```
<array name="backgroundcolors">
```

to

```
<string-array name="backgroundcolors">
```